# Mixed Model: Ridge Regression and Data Augmentation

Tags: mixed-model, optimization, least-squares, ridge-regression

Supposed I have a mixed model in the form: $$y = X\beta + Zu+ \varepsilon$$

If I want to enforce a constraint on the $\beta$s can I follow the data augmentation approach that @whuber  mentioned here: [How to apply a soft coefficient constraint to an OLS regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15991/how-to-apply-a-soft-coefficient-constraint-to-an-ols-regression)? What is the best way to enforce coefficient constraints through data augmentation for a linear mixed model?

Answer (score 0):

No @whuber was not really recommending this approach. I would say the standard software approach, at least in R, is using offset.

Ie if you want to regularise around b instead of 0, then add an offset of Xb, then your coefficients are for (Beta-b)

See offset Param in

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-21/topics/lmer

Comment: What do you mean by "le" Also, I am using SAS currently. Why wouldn't the data augmentation approach be recommended?

Comment: from whubers response:"Although you can obtain the solution ̂  this way, I doubt any of the statistics coming out of this fit will be meaningful."